# Android: Which dimens.xml file picked for what screen size?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, text-size

If I have a table layout with say 2 rows and 2 columns. Each quadrant table box has static text like "box_11", "box_12", "box_21",  "box_22". I want the text size to be bigger for bigger screen and smaller for small screens. I want the text to scale according to the screen size. How should I do it?
I guess I should be using dimens.xml file, defining:  
`<dimen name="activity_text_size">15sp</dimen>`
Then I should be using     `android:textSize="@dimen/activity_text_size"`
I see that there are different "values" directories like values, values-sw600dp, values-sw720dp_land, values-v11, values-v14 in my project workspace. Each 'values'directory can have a dimens.xml file. On what basis a dimens.xml is picked when you have multiple files?

Comment: Explanation here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch

Comment: sp is supposed to scale (that's what it means, scaling independent pixel). Don't start creating different dimensions unless you actually need them. And when you begin fixing a font problem, focus on using different density qualifiers, not different layout size qualifiers.

Answer (score 1):

for example:

//into dimen.xml(600dp)

`<resources>
    <dimen name="activity_text_size">15dp</dimen>
</resources>`

//into dimen.xml(sw720dp_land)

`<resources>
    <dimen name="activity_text_size">20dp</dimen>
</resources>`

//into dimen.xml(w820dp)

`<resources>
    <dimen name="activity_text_size">25dp</dimen>
</resources>`

and for any size of screen you shoud use specific dimen.xml(your size target )and use same dimen.name for it .

Answer (score 0):

With reference to @matiash's link and another official resource:
 - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch
 - https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

The 'standard' densities that are catered for are:

> A set of six generalized densities:
>
> 1. ldpi (low) ~120dpi
> 2. mdpi (medium) ~160dpi
> 3. hdpi (high) ~240dpi
> 4. xhdpi (extra-high) ~320dpi
> 5. xxhdpi (extra-extra-high) ~480dpi
> 6. xxxhdpi (extra-extra-extra-high) ~640dpi

When you create your application with multiple dimen.xml files, the one that is suited for that screen size is chosen.

If in the instance that a resource is not provided for that specific screen density:

> If no matching resource is available, the system uses the default resource and scales it up or down as needed to match the current screen size and density

Hope this helps you :)